# Decide whether the set A of positive integers divisible by 17 and B the set of positive integers divisible by 11 are in bijection.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Decide whether the set A of positive integers divisible by 17 and B the set of positive integers
divisible by 11 are in bijection.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 2):

The both sets are infinite and subset of a nunmerable set, thus they have the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$

Let $A$ be the set of positive integers divisible by $11$ and $B$ the set of positive integer divisible by $17$, $f:A\rightarrow B$ defined by $f(x)=17{x\over 11}$ is the inverse of $g:B\rightarrow A$ defined by $g(x)=11{x\over 17}$

Answer (score 0):

The set of all integers divisible by $17$ is $17\mathbb Z =\{17n|n\in \mathbb Z\}$.  The set of all integers divisible by $11$ is $11 \mathbb Z=\{11n|n\in \mathbb Z\}$.

A bijection $f:17\mathbb Z \to 11\mathbb Z$, is a function so that if $x\in 17\mathbb Z$ then $f(x) = y$ is $y \in 11 \mathbb Z$.

If $x \in 17\mathbb Z$ then there is a $k$ so that $x = 17k$ and $y \in 11\mathbb Z$ then there is an $m$ so that $y= 11m$.

We need a way of mapping some $17k$ to some $11m$.

One obvious way is if $f(17k) = 11m$ so that $17k\mapsto 11k$ and we have $17\mapsto 11;34\mapsto 22, 51\mapsto 33$ etc.

That is if $x = 17k$ then $k =\frac x{17}$ and $f(x) = 11k = 11\cdot \frac {x}{17}=\frac {11}{17}x$.

So the three things to ask ourselves.

1) Is $f:17\mathbb Z \to 11\mathbb Z$ a function?

For every $x = 17k$ where $k$ is an integer, does $f(x) = \frac {11}{17}x$ equal so $y = 11m$ where $m$ is an integer?

So ..... answer that.

2) Is $f:17\mathbb Z \to 11\mathbb Z$  surjective?

For every $y = 11m$ where $m$ is an integer,  is there some $x = 17k$ where $f(x)=11m$?

Try solving.  Does $\frac {11}{17}x = 11m$ always have a solution of the form $x=17k$?  What happens when you try to solve.

3) is $f:17\mathbb Z \to 11\mathbb Z$ injective.

If $f(x) = y$ is $x$ unique?  If $y = 11m$ and $x_1 = 17j$ and $x_2 = 17k$ and $f(x_1) = y$ and $f(x_2) = y$.  Does that *always* mean that $x_1 = x_2$.

If $f(x_1) = \frac {11}{17}x_1= \frac {11}{17}17j = 11m$ and if $f(x_2)=\frac {11}{17}x_2 = \frac {11}{17}k = 11m$ so that mean $17j = 17k$?

If the answer to the three questions are yes, than $f$ is a bijection between $17\mathbb Z$ and $11\mathbb Z$.